# Sitecore 8.2 license file in Sitecore 9.0.1

Tags: licensing

I am using Sitecore 8.2 license file with Sitecore 9. I can see Sitecore.xDB.Base in the list of installed licenses but I am not sure if this is sufficient. Can use of Sitecore 8.2 licenses suppress some of the Sitecore 9 (or any module) functionalities?

Answer (score 5):

No, the Sitecore 8.2 license file is the same as the one used for 9. Anything licensed under 8.2 should continue to be licensed under 9.

Comment: One exception could be the JSS server https://jss.sitecore.net/#/requirements

Comment: And Device Detection is included as standard in Sitecore 9.0 now, which also [requires a valid license](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/90/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_90_Initial_Release.aspx) (and may therefore need to be updated)

Comment: I would also warn that not all licenses are the same. Licenses can vary and some 8.2 licenses do not work on 9 installs depending on how your license was procured.